# Shared world where our earth is invaded by a parallel universe

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

I have never read these. I remember being told about them a few years ago. These are a series of shared world stories where our earth is invaded by a parallel universe. The parallel universe has military technology at the level of muskets and I believe they have some kind of floating ships as well. The statement I remember is that it was 'natural' for them to develop that way.

The person also told me there was at least one story where the SWAT team beat them back. The parallel universe invading us had invaded other parallel universes also.

Comment: Any idea how old these stories are?  Roughly how many are in the series? (2 or 3? a dozen? dozens?).  Any idea if they were all by the same author?

Answer (score 5):

Not a shared world, and not an alternate universe, but Turtledove's short "The Road Not Taken" might be of interest to you - where furrigners (heh) have muskets and come to invade Earth, after having conquered many other planets.

Answer (score 4):

These may have been the stories based upon the Torg roleplaying game. In Torg's setting, multiple alien parallels are invading "Core Earth".

The key elements are the use of stellae to convert Core Earth over to the invaders' own sets of different physics.